# Update wordpress Advance custom field on 40,000 existing posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 40000 posts on my website. Yesterday I created a new advanced custom field with a default value. When I open any existing post, The default value does not show up, however when I hit update button or create new post, The default value shows up.

I found a script online to put in function.php file that updates the values automatically. The script is

```
add_action('admin_init', 'set_default_acf_values');

function set_default_acf_values() {

$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'chemicals',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
];

   $posts = get_posts($args);

   foreach($posts as $post) 
    {
         if (empty(get_field('stock_1', $post->ID))) {
         update_field('stock_1', DEFAULT_AD_LINK, $post->ID);
    }





}
}
```

however when I run the script it shows me a memory error.

```
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 916 of file wp-includes/meta.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

I believe the reason it is showing memory error because are too many posts.

I also increase memory limit in wp-config.php file, but it did not help at all

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

What I am looking for is a way to fetch default value from NEW fields on existing posts OR update all existing posts without getting memory error.

any help or pointer would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks

Comment: if that's the issue you can run code for first 10000 only and check. then use offset to skip those posts.

Comment: @Chilll007 thanks for your reply, My PHP skills are not strong, Can you plz update the code in original post with your offset code in it ?

Comment: you could also create an AJAX call for it, so that it can run 1 or a 100 by a time, until it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code.

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'chemicals',
    'posts_per_page' => 10000,
];

   $posts = get_posts($args);

   foreach($posts as $post) 
    {
         if (empty(get_field('stock_1', $post->ID))) {
         update_field('stock_1', DEFAULT_AD_LINK, $post->ID);
    }
```

after that you can use

```
$args = [
        'post_type'      => 'chemicals',
        'offset'  => 10000,
        'posts_per_page' => 10000,
    ];

       $posts = get_posts($args);

       foreach($posts as $post) 
        {
             if (empty(get_field('stock_1', $post->ID))) {
             update_field('stock_1', DEFAULT_AD_LINK, $post->ID);
        }
```

it will give you next 10000 post which start from 10001

Comment: @chill007 will it update first 10000 posts? If yes then I tried to run code with 100 posts and checked randomly some beginning posts and it did not update them.

Comment: yes it will update those posts. maybe some issue with your code.